# Split string separated by multiple spaces, ignoring single spaces

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split a string separated by multiple spaces. For example:

```
"AAAA AAA        BBBB BBB BBB        CCCCCCCC"
```

I want to split it into these:

```
"AAAA AAA"   
"BBBB BBB BBB"
"CCCCCCCC"
```

I tried with this code:

```
value2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(stringvalue, @"\s+");
```

But not success, I only want to split the string by multiple spaces, not by single space.

Comment: How many spaces could there be between items?

Comment: does it have to be done with RegEx?

Comment: They are separated by more than one space. It doesn't matter how many.. The point is to ignore the single space.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`+` means "one or more", so a single space would qualify as a separator. If you want to require more than once, use `{m,n}`:

```
value2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( stringvalue, @"\s{2,}");
```

The `{m,n}` expression requires the expression immediately prior to it match `m` to `n` times, inclusive. Only one limit is required. If the upper limit is missing, it means "`m` or more repetitions".

Answer (score 2):

```
value2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( stringvalue, @"\s{2,}");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
value2 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split( stringvalue, @"\s\s+");
```